# How can I implement a list of subclass from a class in python's owlready2?

Tags: python, owlready

I want to get all the subclasses for each class in a ontology built on protege and imported into python using owlready2.
How can I create a list of all the subclasses for a set class of this ontology ?

Comment: What is your input? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `list(class_name.subclasses())`

Answer (score 0):

```
You can dynamically create classes or sub classes.

import types
class_name = "MyClass"
parent_class = [Thing]
with onto:
    NewClass = types.new_class(class_name, tuple(parent_class))


Please note the new_class() function expects a tuple with the parent
classes and reference of parent class will be passed not string. If your parent class present inside the ontology you can access (onto["parent_class"])
```

Comment: Source : Ontologies with Python Programming OWL 2.0 Ontologies
with Python and Owlready2
By Lamy Jean-Baptiste